# Does the 'Sight' attachment improve the car weapons or the cars' stats?

Tags: death-rally-2012

The 'Sight' attachment puts a laser pointer in your car that is visible while racing. I reckon this is to help the player target straight-firing weapons.

Aside from that, what does the 'Sight' attachment do? Does it improve the car weapons or the cars' stats in another way?

[image]

Comment: I think it only adds the laser sight and nothing more. At least that's what I experienced. Kind of a useless upgrade, to be honest.